# In-app subscriptions remain "purchased" after cancellation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I know it has been asked a few times here but still there's no answer explaining why it happens:

1. Buy the subscription. (subscription is added in my beta draft of the app in the developer console)
2. Cancel it in my phone's google play account
3. Query the inventory and get:

   ```
   {
    "packageName":"",
    "productId":,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "autoRenewing":true
   }
   ```

Obviously the purchase state should be 1 (Cancelled). I tried querying after 12 hours - still same. Am I missing something?

Comment: hey have you tired it after 24hours.? let me know if you are getting the same reposne.

Comment: I've waited 24 hours and the purchase state is still 0. I wonder if it's a testing bug and would switch to cancelled after the actual billing cycle, not the test cycle?

Comment: @Robert, Does the state changed to 1 after the actual billing cycle?

Answer (score 3):

Might be this reason..

[From Developer Docs -Subscription Cancellation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation)

> When the user cancels a subscription, Google Play does not offer a
>   refund for the current billing cycle. Instead, it allows the user to
>   have access to the canceled subscription until the end of the current
>   billing cycle, at which time it terminates the subscription.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I believe the purchaseState == Cancelled is misleading and does not necessarily refer to having canceled the subscription on the user's google play settings, but other cancelation reasons that terminate the subscription.

Comment: This is not the right answer - the docs state `autoRenewing boolean Whether the subscription will automatically be renewed when it reaches its current expiry time.` I have the same problem, I can cancel the subscription via Google Play website or Google Play App, yet I stay subscribed on a test subscription and there seems to be no way out.